# Importing CSV file with semicolon delimiters from S3 to RDS Postgres database

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I am trying to import a CSV file that uses semicolons `;` as delimiters instead of commas from S3 to AWS RDS Postgres table.

```sql
SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3 ('tmp_foo','','(format csv, delimiter '','', header)', 'my-bucket', 'path/file.csv','eu-west-1');
```

This fails with error

```
ERROR: Semicolon is not allowed in options
```

Same thing using `delimiter '',''` works fine.

How to escape semicolon so that it works? For example `delimiter ''\;''` doesn't work.

Importing from S3 is AWS extension available in recent RDS Postgres versions:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Procedural.Importing.html

I am using Postgres Aurora 11.6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I asked about this from the AWS Support and they confirmed that semicolon is not supported as a delimiter. Changing this probably won't happen anytime soon.